# TYPO3 - TCA: required property for type-> 'select'

Tags: select, typo3

in an extension, I have an issue with the required select.

I tried to use   `'eval' => 'required',` in the TCA configuration to make the field of selecting a table required, but in the BE, it's still always not required, and I can save the form even without choosing a table, so maybe it works only with the type 'input'.

how can I fixe that?

This is the TCA:

```
 'name' => array(
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:ext_key/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_ext_domain_model_name.firstname',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
            'eval' => 'required',
            'items' => array(

    
'items' => array(
                array('LLL:EXT:ext_key/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_ext_domain_model_name.firstname'.choose', 0),
            ),
            'size' => 1,
            'maxitems' => 1,
            'itemsProcFunc' => 'Vendor\Extension\Utility\ProcFuncUtility->getName', );
```

Comment: Please post your full TCA for the field in question.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Done!

Comment: Are you sure this is the *full* TCA? You don't have any `items` ...

Comment: Sorry, i completed it

Comment: I guess, your itemsprocfunc always returns values which are not null / false? In this case you always have a selection, so the evaluation works correctly. You need to add a prompt value at the beginning of the array, which returns 0.

Comment: but concerning the eval, it should work when I'm filling the form in the BE, i can't save the it before choosing a field, but thats not my case, I can save without choosing even the 'title' is not required, but there is no errors, the extension works normally, but to be better, I prefer to make those fields required...

Comment: I tried the  'eval' => 'required' for the field "title" (type = input) and it works, now it's required, but for the type select, it's always the same, NOT WORKING!

Comment: Can you post the values of your select fields to your question?

Comment: They are all tables, the field by default is: 'select a table' with uid = 0, then the others are tables like: tx_myext_domain_model_field, or the tables for the propreties by default like: 'sys_category', I'm sorry i can't copy them all, but something like that

Answer (score 0):

There is no `eval` property for select/selectSingle (see https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/10.4/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/selectSingle.html#properties).

Comment: I saw the documentation,and I didn't find anything, that's why I'm  asking, so there is no way to make this required?

Comment: In a (single) selectbox, there is always one option selected. It's to you, to define which is the default option. Especially for BE forms, it's a good idea to give editors good default values.

Comment: yeah I gave a default value, it's: 'choose a table' with parentId = 0, always, but the user can pass this step without choosing, and i can't choose a table and set it like default bcz it's not appropriate with mu idea, in all cases, it's secondary problem bcw the extension works well

Comment: Hm, ok... If you need the "Please choose..."-option, maybe the special '--div--' value for items can help you: "The special value --div-- is used to insert a non-selectable value that appears as a divider label in the selector box"

Comment: Okay great, I think that's the better solution for this case, I wanted to use it before, but I said maybe I can find something else, thank you!